# Looping (for) through some data, concatenating along the way, appending to a list in final, but dimensions don't match in python

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the code:

```
#new_right_v2 = []
for i in range(rows):
    r1_p5_first_half = np.concatenate( (new_right[i,:312].reshape(1,-1), new_right[i,625:937].reshape(1,-1), new_right[i,1250:1562].reshape(1,-1), new_right[i,1875:2187].reshape(1,-1)),axis=1)
    #print(r1_p5_first_half.shape)
    r1_p5_second_half = np.concatenate( (new_right[i,313:625].reshape(1,-1), new_right[i,938:1250].reshape(1,-1), new_right[i,1563:1875].reshape(1,-1), new_right[i,2187:2499].reshape(1,-1)),axis=1)
    
    new_right_v2.append(r1_p5_first_half)
    new_right_v2.append(r1_p5_second_half)
    new_right_v2
```

But when I run to check dimensions:

```
for i in range(40):
    print(new_right_v2[i].shape)
```

This output comes:
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(2, 1248)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)
(4, 624)

I don't know what happens after 10th iteration. Any idea?

Comment: Double check the slices like `(new_right[i,313:625]`.  If you slice off-the-end, you just get a shorter array, not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually not sure what dimensions are you checking, as `new_right_v2` seems to be a list

Maybe you can apply the operations matrix-wise to all rows at once?

```
first_half = np.concatenate(
    new_right[:,:312],
    new_right[:,625:937],
    new_right[:,1250:1562],
    new_right[:,1875:2187])
).T
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, actually because I was using jupyter notebook, I lost track of the variable which I have changed somewhere else. When I restarted and runned the code, I got what I want. But your way is more compact and better btw, thanks.